# WDK 8.1 fails with Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-8, msbuild, windows-8.1, wdk

I am trying to build a project using WDK 8.1 and Visual Studio 2012 under Windows 8. I do not have Visual Studio 2013 Preview installed, however according to the requirements page I have fulfilled all the requirements:

[WDK 8.1 Requirements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn308552%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#system_requirements)

That page says:

> System Requirements Before you install the WDK, you must first install
>   Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2012 or above.

My project was created using WDK 8.0 so I followed the instructions provided here for migrating to WDK 8.1:

[ProjectUpgradeTool: Upgrade a WDK 8 project or solution to WDK 8.1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn265174%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

While running the command:

```
ProjectUpgradeTool.exe C:\Sources\MyDriver
```

I got the following error:

> Catastrophic failure while converting projects under
>   'C:\Sources\MyDriver':    Message:Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Build, Version=12.0.0.0    , Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependenc    ies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.
>       StackTrace=
>         at Microsoft.DriverKit.ProjectUpgradeTool.ProjectUpgrader.UpgradeProjec
>   ts(IEnumerable`1 projectFiles)
>         at Microsoft.DriverKit.ProjectUpgradeTool.Upgrader.UpgradeProjects(IEnu
>
>   merable`1 files, String newOsConfigName)

Does anyone have a hint on how to get around this error?

**Update as of Jan 12 2014**

The documentation has been modified since I posted this question, and it clearly states now that VS2013 is indeed required for WDK8.1 development.

Same question in [MSDN forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c825d4ec-8326-4df1-809a-d87f826dde4c/wdk-81-fails-with-visual-studio-2012)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first item in the system requirements on the [page that you have linked to](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn308552%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#system_requirements) clearly states that Visual Studio 2013 is required to use WDK 8.1:

> Before you install WDK 8.1, you must first install Visual Studio 2013.

You will need to keep using WDK 8 with Visual Studio 2012, although it's [not officially supported any more](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/hh852365.aspx):

> We provide Windows Driver Kit (WDK) 8 to give you time to migrate to
>   WDK 8.1 and Visual Studio 2013. Microsoft does not support WDK 8 and
>   will make no further updates to WDK 8. We recommend that you use the
>   latest versions of the WDK and Visual Studio to build drivers for
>   Windows. Download the Windows Driver Kit (WDK) 8, which has tools to
>   build, test, debug, and deploy drivers.

Comment: That page has been changed since I posted the question, but thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use WDK with Visual Studio 2012, you should get not 8.1 version but 8.0 of WDK.

Comment: What if I am using Visual studio 2015? Namke2MSbuild giving same error.

Answer (score 1):

You need [Visual Studio 2013](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/2013-downloads#d-2013-editions) to develop for Windows 8.1 I believe.

Answer (score 0):

If you have both WDK 8.0 and 8.1 installed, the active one is specified using %WDKContentRoot% env var. Your vcxproj likely references the WDK by this variable so may have to change it.